# Warning: #1262 Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I import a CSV file to my table with PHPMyAdmin and the import I am getting this warning:

> Warning: #1262 Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there
>   were input columns

Is that necessarily warning? or we can ignore that warning? and what that's warning means?

[image: image of the warning]

Comment: Without knowing your input data, this could mean that the data contains an un-escaped delimiter in a value. See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191925/row-n-was-truncated-it-contained-more-data-than-there-were-input-columns-only)

Comment: Does your data have headers, have you setup the database to import this data into, or is it being created as part of the import? -- It's saying 'You told me you'd provide data a,b and c, but you've provided a,b,c, and z'

Comment: Not knowing the input data makes it impossible to answer this question, but I had the same error and it turned out to be a line ending problem. This answer solved by problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843561/2182703